# Window Batch file to keep some specific folders and delete the rest

Tags: batch-file, del, rmdir

I have 100+ folders, and I want to run a batch file to keep certain folders like 10 folders with different names based on my list. Example I have folders like

```
1FL-12
1FL-44
1FL-86
2FL-95
2FL-73
2FL-25
3FL-52
4FL-53
4FL-35
5FL-85
```

I am trying to keep only the folder 2FL-95, 2FL-73 and 2FL-25 and delete the rest. Before I tried using `rmdir /S /Q "C:\pathtodirectory"` to delete the unwanted ones but its not that convenient when there are just too many folders to delete.

Is there any simpler way to keep only the folders and delete the rest?

Comment: `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /ad /b * ^|findstr /v "2FL-95 2FL-73 2FL-25"') DO rd /s /q "%%G"`